# How to create a UIPathRobot Virtual Machine using terraform in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, terraform-provider-azure, uipath-robot

I have created virtual networks, subnets, and network security groups using Terraform. Next, I want to create a UIPathRobot virtual machine along with custom extensions inside the existing virtual network, subnet, and NSG.

How to create a UIPathRobot Virtual Machine using terraform in Azure?

Answer (score 0):

There is no available document to create `UIPathRobot` virtual machine using terraform. Till now Azure marketplace deployments allow you to deploy UiPath solutions directly from the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/).

[image]

You can refer this [link](https://docs.uipath.com/installation-and-upgrade/docs/robot-azure-marketplace-deployment) for more information. You can raise a `github` issue  for the same might someone from community team might help to build this.